# sample_weight not working in Sklearn in GridSearch with pipeline

Tags: grid-search

I am stuck in one problem for days. I need to use sample_weight to the classifiers and something should be easy, I do not find the way.I hope if someone can help (scikit-image                       0.16.2 scikit-learn  1.0.2)

> fit_params = {"sample_weight":  sample_weight_classifier}
> grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=cv_inner, scoring=opt_score,verbose=10, refit=True,**fit_params)

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'

I tried all the options and ways and no possible. Any solution?.

Thank you